# How to set 100% width to first table td and make other td's to be below first td

Tags: html, css, html-table

I need to make first `td` 100% wide (which has image included) and put other `td's` below first `td`. How to do this without changing HTML?

**This is what I have:**

```
#katalogas { float:left; width:100%; }
#katalogas .lentele { border-collapse:collapse; width:100% !important; }
#katalogas table.lentele tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) td {  width:25% !important;     border:1px dashed black; }
```

**[Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/s3qatL1c/1/)**

Any way to do this?

Comment: You want the image above or below the table headings? It's not that clear what you want.

Comment: First td should be 100% wide. And others should be below first one.

Comment: @Tauras What are the similarities in those 200 tables? Like same Class Name or something else.

Comment: @divy3993 None. In jsfiddle there is one table. Every other table is same.

Comment: Are these 200 tables stored seperately?

Comment: @LGSon those tables is directly included in wordpress text editor. As i said, there is tons of them... it would be pain to change html in all of them

Comment: @Tauras Is their(200's of them) id's similar? Or do you have it live, so that we can have a look at it.

Comment: @divy3993 There is no id's directly in table tag. http://darbastau.lt/betfix/category/prekiu-katalogas/

Comment: @divy3993 How you are doing? :/

Comment: Are these tables generated dynamically in Wordpress? .. Are the data in the tables stored in a database or the whole table is stored as is?

Comment: No. Data is not stored. Tables are created in wordpress text/content editor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I made it work this far ... tested in latest Chrome, FF, IE/Edge

[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/s3qatL1c/3/)

where I added the following to your fiddle css:

```
/* new css added ... */
#katalogas .lentele { position:relative; margin-top: 150px }
#katalogas .lentele img { position: absolute; top: -150px; }
#katalogas table.lentele tbody tr:nth-of-type(1) td:nth-of-type(1) { width: 0 !important; border: 0 }
```

This works if you can set the same height on all images, if not, each that does not, need to be addressed individually, though like less than 200 :)

Comment: Thats great. Thank you very much. Couple of times, in this community, i saw that people dont want to waste time in other people problems in code. I asked question 1 hour ago, and after that, i got a great answer. Thank you very much, for not being that person :)

Comment: Prašom ... and I didn't just helped because my wife is Lithuanian :)

Comment: :D sekmes programavime! :)

Answer (score 0):

Put it in its own row and use `colspan`:

```
 <tr><td colspan="4">image here</td></tr>
```

**Demo:** http://codepen.io/anon/pen/BozGyP

Comment: Thats great. Is there possible way to do this wihout changing HTML?

Comment: @Tauras Why do you want to do that without changing the HTML?

Comment: Not really, table formatting is a particular type of layout where the markup is fairly hard to manipulate too much with CSS.